# (yet another) rake assets:precompile is slow while deploying to Heroku

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

Just as many others here I am having issues with the pre-compilation of my assets when deploying to Heroku. I've tried nearly all of the suggestions found here, but to no avail. I am using Ruby 1.9.3 and turbo-sprockets-rails-3 and set `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false`.

I am precompiling multiple (5) .js and .css files. What I have noticed is that the pre-compilation of each file seems to be reasonably quick (between 0.2 and 25s per file), but the total time is around 6 mins. When watching the logs I can see each file getting pre-compiled quickly, but then it seems to be idling between each file for a long time before continuing. Or at least it seems that way, because there is no further output.

Any ideas of what might be going on or how I could get more detailed debug output to let me pinpoint the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do you sync to AWS S3 maybe, did you set correctly FOG_REGION ?

Comment: I don't believe I am syncing to AWS. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Do you sync your assets to Amazon S3 bucket or some kind of CDN ?

Comment: No, I don't I'm afraid.